# После переноса сайта с боевого хостинга на локальный сломался minifyx. Как исправить?

Tags: modx

Я перенес сайт на локалку с боевого хостинга. И теперь у меня то, что подключалось в css, не подключается (шрифты, картинки...). Точнее, подключается, но неправильно. Пропускается имя сайта. Вот, например:

```
http://assets/template/images/img.png
```

А имени сайта перед assets нет. Почему так? В настройках контекстов я поменял host и site_url. В системных настройках я поменял site_name. Что я забыл?

Если подключать скрипты не через minifyx, а стандартным способом, то все работает.

Comment: Кеш чистили? какая версия MODX? в config.inc.php тоже поменяли? Как вариант попробуйте переустановить minifyX

Comment: @AntonTarasov, пробовал все это - не помогло. Если залить на хостинг, то там все норм. У меня на локалке не рабоатает. При том, что сначала я этот сайт и разрабатывал на локалке, потом залил на хостинг, потом с хостинга слил снова на локалку. 

Версия CMS: modx 2.7.3-pl.